# jqtouch and redirecting

Tags: javascript, jqtouch

I am using JQTouch and I am trying to load a new page into the current page. Unfortunately JQTouch automatically adds a '#' to the url and thus the url cannot be opened.

in order words,

```
<li class="arrow"><a href="categories.html">Categories</a></li>
```

would not work.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
C.

Answer (score 1):

To link to external url's in jqtouch you have to use the target="_webapp".  I.e. change your html to:

```
<li class="arrow"><a href="categories.html" target="_webapp">Categories</a></li>
```